# Excel VBA Find Doesn't Find the Value (Office 2016 Mac)

Tags: excel, vba, macos, csv

I have a function that reads from a csv file, and then looks for the value in the workbook.
When I ran the code in windows, it worked, but on mac it seems to fail to find the value, even though it exists.
The main function is:

```
Private Sub ReadCSV_Click()
    Dim key As String
    Dim loc As String
    loc_idx = -1
    Dim FilePath As String
    FilePath = ThisWorkbook.Path + "/test.csv"
    Open FilePath For Input As #1
    row_number = 0

    Do Until EOF(1)
        Line Input #1, LineFromFile
        LineItems = Split(LineFromFile, ",")
        loc = Replace(CStr(LineItems(0)), Chr(34), vbNullString)
        If Not loc = vbNullString Then
            key = Replace(CStr(LineItems(1)), Chr(34), vbNullString)
            Call SearchCell(key)
            Call SearchLocationCol(f_ws_idx)
            Worksheets(f_ws_idx).Cells(f_row, loc_idx).Value = loc
        End If
        row_number = row_number + 1
    Loop

    Close #1
    MsgBox "Done Updating"
End Sub
```

The SearchCell function:

```
Private Sub SearchCell(SN As String)
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rFound As Range
    Dim i As Integer
    If SN = "" Then Exit Sub

    For i = Worksheets.Count To 1 Step -1
        With Worksheets.Item(i).UsedRange
            Debug.Print Worksheets.Item(i).Name
            'Debug.Print CStr(VarType(SN))
            Set rFound = .Find(What:=SN, After:=.Cells(.Cells.Count), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
            If Not rFound Is Nothing Then
                f_col = rFound.Column
                f_row = rFound.Row
                f_ws_idx = i
                Exit Sub
            End If
        End With
    Next i
End Sub
```

It just doesn't ever find the value. But if I enter the key that I'm looking for right into the Find method, e.g.: What:="123456" it does find it. So, the search itself still works, but for some reason the value it reads from the csv isn't found that way?
I've tried to debug it at it reads that values properly from the csv.
The csv itself is pretty basic:

```
"Test","123456"
"Test2","11111"
```

Any suggestions to why it won't work? Probably something basic that I'm missing here, but I'm really stuck on this one.

Thanks.

Comment: Just a thought, probsbly way off target, but how are the things you're looking for stored on the worksheet? You're working hard to make your search string-based, but so far you're looking for numbers. Are the numbers on the sheets stored as strings? Also, you're looking at xlWhole; do the numbers stored have spaces or other characters around them?

Comment: I'm converting it to a string because there are keys that can be strings (e.g AD156D). And they may have spaces around them

Comment: Does the code work with "AD156D"? Is the problem only with numeric strings?

Comment: I've suspected it before, but the code doesn't work for "AD156D" as well

Comment: Can you check the `key` value just before `Call SearchCell(key)` to check if the replace worked properly?

Comment: I am checking it right before calling the function, I just removed the Debug.Print that I had from the code here to make it a little bit neater :) And yes, the key value is what I expect it to be

Comment: You say if you enter the key into the `find` method like `What:="123456"` it does find the key. Does it also find the key if you put it into the function call like `Call SearchCell("123456")`? If yes, then there **must** be a difference between the variable `key` and the string `"123456"`.

Comment: You're right, it seems to work that way. But what can be the problem? I just took the output of `Debug.Print serial` and put it inside the brackets. Also, when testing wether `key="123456"` I get a false. How can I find the difference?

Comment: Try to test for spaces before/after in the `key`: You can print a `#` as delimiter before and after to see if there are additional (invisible) spaces `Debug.Print "#" & key & "#"`. Or compare the length of `key` (`len(key)`) with the length of the working string .

Comment: Thanks! Apparently  I had a carriage return in the end of `key` that I did not take care of. Once removing it the string seems fine :)